# add negative values to the progress bar

Tags: qt

I have a realtime value from a sensor:

```
 ui->progressBar_retraction->setValue(aX*100); //aX is realtime value that can take positive or negative values over time
```

In the above expression, the progress bar shown the instantaneous *positive* values of `aX`.

How do I show *negative* values in a different `progress bar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

◘ Well, **if you want to use another QProgressBar**, you obviously need another one. Then simply check the sign of `aX` and update one of the two accordingly :

```
if(aX < 0){

     progress_bar_neg->setValue(qAbs(aX)*100);
     progress_bar_pos->setValue(0);

}else{

     progress_bar_pos->setValue(aX*100);
     progress_bar_neg->setValue(0);

}
```

*Note that if you want one of your `QProgressbar` to fill from right to left, you can use `void setInvertedAppearance(bool invert)` to set its `invertedAppearance` to `true`.*

◘ **Another alternative using the same `QProgressBar`** could look like :

```
 ui->progressBar_retraction->setValue(qAbs(aX)*100);
 if(aX < 0){/*Set to a colour*/}
 else{/*Set to another colour*}
```

To edit the colour :

```
QPalette p;
p.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, Qt::red); //Change background colour, here red
ui->progressBar_retraction->setPalette(p);
p.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText , Qt::black); //Change text colour, here black
ui->progressBar_retraction->setPalette(p);
```

◘ **If you want a bi-directional QProgessBar**, it is unfortunately not possible by only calling a method as far as I know (correct me if I am wrong).

What I did was an override of `void QProgressBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` to start the drawing of the rectangle from the middle. You then simply fix the range of the `QProgressBar` with `void QProgressBar::setRange(int minimum, int maximum)`. You may even update the colour to make it a bit simpler to see.